# Jmeter --I am unable to understand why my Jmeter script is not taking dynamic session_code for my application...any help would be appreciated

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies

I am unable to understand why my Jmeter script is not taking dynamic session_code for my application...any help would be appreciated

Jmeter script can be viewed with this link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CDe2msEd2v8_UKe9OjQoigtFxP1i2OAT/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Can you upload to something more public like github